# Issues with final output

Tags: python, list, function

Expected Output :
[image: Expected Output]

I was working on the functions to get the code for elementary cellular automaton. I got all the outputs correct but I could not get my desired output printed.

```
def main():
    N= int(input("Enter number of steps,N:"))
    C= int(input("Enter number of cells,C:"))
    i_list=list(map(int,input("Enter the indices of occupied cells (space-separated):").split()))
    cell= [0]*C
    for i in i_list:
        cell[int(i)] = 1
        displayCells(cell)
    for step in range(N):
        newCells = updateCells(cell)
        displayCells(newCells)
        cells = []
        cells += newCells      # concatenates new state to new list


def displayCells(Cells):
    for cell in Cells:
        if cell == 1:
            print("#", end='')
def updateCells(cells):
    nc = []          # makes a new empty list
    nc += cells      # copy current state into new list
    for a in range(1, len(nc)-1):
        if nc[a-1] == 1 and nc[a] == 1 and nc[a+1] == 1:
            nc[a] = 0
        elif nc[a-1] == 1 and nc[a] == 1 and nc[a+1] == 0:
            nc[a] = 1
        elif nc[a-1] == 1 and nc[a] == 0 and nc[a+1] == 1:
            nc[a] = 1
        elif nc[a-1] == 1 and nc[a] == 0 and nc[a+1] == 0:
            nc[a] = 0
        elif nc[a-1] == 0 and nc[a] == 1 and nc[a+1] == 1:
            nc[a] = 1
        elif nc[a-1] == 0 and nc[a] == 1 and nc[a+1] == 0:
            nc[a] = 1
        elif nc[a-1] == 0 and nc[a] == 0 and nc[a+1] == 1:
            nc[a] = 1
        else:
            nc[a] = 0
    return nc

main()
```

I expect the output to be the loop that follows the rule of updateCells function and draw the # whenever the program sees 1.

Comment: instead of `cells = []` and `cells += newCells` you can use one line `cells = newCells`

Comment: the same with `nc = []` , `nc += cells`  -> `nc = cells`

Comment: you `print('#')` but you forgot to print spaces between `#`

Comment: you print all in one line - I don't see `\n` or `print()`

Comment: Where should I put my /n?

Comment: At the end of `displayCells`.

Comment: not `/n` but `\n` ("new line")